# Sniper simulator installation

Tags: 20.04

I have downloaded the latest sniper emulator version 7.4, and I noticed that it is divided into two folders (sniper-7.4 and sniper-7.4-pin2). I do not know how to proceed with my installation, what is the difference between the two folders, the explanation of the official website stays in version 7.2. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Getting Started page](https://snipersim.org/w/Getting_Started) for the simulator:

> The master branch of Sniper works with modern Pin versions (Pin 3.0+), while the pin2 branch works with older versions (Pin 2.14-71313). We recommend using a modern Pin 3 version if possible.

If you have installed [the more recent version of Pin from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.html), then you will use `sniper-7.4`. If you are using an older version of Pin, then use `sniper-7.4-pin2`.

From the documentation that I can find about Pin release dates, you are almost certainly using a 3.x version – if it has been installed at all.

Comment: I noticed in the sniper7.4 update that pin3.18 will be automatically downloaded, so I don't think I need to manually download the pin myself